# Could I figure out the sun's size in the sky based on the planet's radius and its length of year?

Tags: science-based, planets, space

I know the planet's radius and how long it takes to orbit it's sun, could I use this information to then work out the size of the star itself and how large it would appear in the sky or would I need more information?

Is there an approximate distance from planet to star that I can rely on considering the planet is meant to be Earth-like.

Comment: This is best asked at Astronomy, there could be more competent people to ask this than here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The planet's size has nothing to do with the appearance of the sun.

However, if you know how much light the planet gets, and its year length, you can work backward to figure out how massive the sun must be, and therefore both how large it is and what color it is, and the angular size of the sun in the sky can then be determined from the actual size of the sun and the distance between the sun and the planet (which you will have worked out in the process of figuring out how big the sun must be to give you the desired light level and year length).

Comment: What's the standard unit for measurement for how much light a planet gets?

Comment: @HarryKorone: Watts per square meter. For example, for Earth, the [solar constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_constant) is about 1.36 kW/m². This measures how much total electromagnetic energy (also known as [irradiance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irradiance)) falls on the unit area at a distance of one astronomical unit from the sun. Some of this energy is reflected back into space and doesn't get to heat anything; the rest of it heats up the sea and the land, and powers photosynthesis. In the end, all of it is re-radiated back into space as thermal infrared.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation